# Using Durandal with Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, durandal

I'm trying to develop a Cordova/Phonegap application using Durandal for IOS (using a Mac), and am having some trouble getting started.

I've got Cordova loading with RequireJs and that's all working fine.  This is what I've got in my main.js file:

```
define(function (require) {

    var
        cordova = require('cordova.ios'),
        system = require('durandal/system'),
        //app = require('durandal/app');

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady () {
        alert('Device is Ready!');
    }
});
```

Notice I have app = require('durandal/app') commented out.  If it **IS** commented out, then everything works fine.  But as soon as I uncomment that, I don't get the alert anymore.  I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the web inspector in Safari, and it seems like the app.js file gets loaded, but it stops everything else from happening there.

I know the docs say that you can use the optimizer, but is there no way to do the actual development in XCode and test without running the optimizer?

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an app variable in cordova, probably due to naming conflict. I created a sample and it worked with durandal. Please let me know if it doesnot work, i will post sample in github

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I assume what you mean is I shouldn't name my variable "app".  I've tried "durandalApp", "dApp", "ladkfj" and none of them work.  If you have a sample I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you still able to link to your example on github?